# Ghostscript does not compress all PDF's

Tags: pdf, compression, ghostscript

I am trying to compress PDFs using Ghostscript. I have a folder of around 5000 PDF files, all of varying sizes (5-1000 pages) and appearances. The `gs` command that I use successfully compresses 2700 of them. However, the remaining 2300, remain uncompressed and in many, cases have increased in size after applying the command. Below is my command which I call through a python script. Please tell me what I should add or remove to ensure that all PDF's are compressed.

```
gs \
   -q \ 
   -dNOPAUSE \
   -dBATCH \ 
   -dSAFER \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \  
   -dSubsetFonts=true \    
   -dUseFlateCompression=true \ 
   -dOptimize=true \
   -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceRGB \  
   -dDownsampleGrayImages=true  \
   -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \ 
   -dGrayImageResolution=150 \
   -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false \
   -dDownsampleMonoImages=true \
   -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
   -dCompressPages=true \
   -dMonoImageResolution=150 \
   -dDownsampleColorImages=true  \
   -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \ 
   -dColorImageResolution=150 \
   -dAutoFilterColorImages=false \
   -dPDFSETTINGS= /screen \
   -sOutputFile = output.pdf
    input.pdf
```

Comment: Your command line is massively over complicated. not only that, but almost all of it is entirely irrelevant. The -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen will override practically everything in the command line before that point. You should **either** set all the parameters individually, **or** use -dPDFSETTINGS, not both. You are also going to have to share a file which demonstrates the problem, as well as explaining how you are determining whether the file is uncompressed or not. Simply checking the fle size does not tell you that.

Comment: And furthermore, the answer might be that the problem input files already are compressed as desired or even compressed better...

Comment: @KenS, I am sorry. I am very new to ghostscript. I made the above command after looking at some other ghostscript commands and combining all of those. I cannot share the file as it contains private information. Can I override the -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen? Can you tell me a better command to compress PDF files? I am really sorry for the inconvenience. I am very new to gs and pdf compression.

Comment: 'override' ? Why not simply omit it if you are going to set all the paramters manually ? All 'PDFSETTINGS' does is set those exact same paramters in  one big lump instead of setting them all individually. Ghostscript doesn' 'compress' PDF files. You should read the documentation in VectorDevices.htm, especially the 'Overview' to see how it works. There is **never** a guarantee that the file produced fng to need to see the filerom Ghostscript will be smaller than the original, unless you do something like dramatically reducing the resolution of images.

Comment: Note that its very likely whenever you ask about PDF files (and especially their contents, like compression), that people are going to need to see the PDF file in order to be able to tell you anything about it. You need to find a file you can share if you are going to ask this kind of question.

Comment: @KenS I am sorry, but I cannot share a file here. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Generally PDF compression is a difficult problem.  Some documents can be very bloated and capable of being reduced greatly in size.  Other documents are very well compressed already.  Some documents aren't necessarily bloated and are already a good size based on their content.

Not all PDF software is created equally, some can work great for particular types of PDFs and others not so much.  Unfortunately there's not a one size fits all answer for why a PDF can't be reduced in size further.